# Cannot work with SherlockFragment

Tags: android, replace, actionbarsherlock, fragment, fragmentmanager

I have a problem with SherlockFragment. 
If I change "extends SherlockFragment" with "Fragment", works perfectly. 
But when working with Sherlock, I would it work this way.

This code is a fragment:

```
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


public class Box extends SherlockFragment {

    public Box(){}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.box, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

In my ActivityMain.java i have this:

```
SherlockFragment fragment = null;
```

*It works with Fragment fragment = null;*

And i call it:

```
fragment= new Box();
```

But the problem is the .replace in this code:

```
 FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
 fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
```

Comment: What does your Activity extend?

Comment: Post the code of your activity please

Comment: My Activity_Main extends Activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the getFragmentManager to getSupportFragmentManager for using sherlockfragment

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
 fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
```